# Swipe feature in Telerik RadDataGrid

Tags: c#, xaml, datagrid, uwp, telerik

I am developing an UWP application where data is represented in tabular form using Data grid, We also have a feature where user can perform swipe on each row on the grid to perform certain actions. Also the data that we are having in the DataGrid needs few feature that cannot be accomplished by ListView.

I am using the open source version of Telerik UWP controls, Is there any way I can add swipe feature in the DataGrid.

Answer (score 1):

The `RadDataGrid` does not  provides support for item swipe gestures.

I recommend using the `RadListView`, it has many of the features of the `DataGrid`, such as [Grouping](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/universal-windows-platform/controls/radlistview/features/listview-grouping), [Sorting](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/universal-windows-platform/controls/radlistview/features/listview-sorting) and [Filtering](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/universal-windows-platform/controls/radlistview/features/listview-filtering). The RadListView control provides support for item swipe gestures. Swiping left or right over the swipe area displays the SwipeActionContent.  For more info, see [Gestures](http://docs.telerik.com/windows-universal/controls/radlistview/features/listview-gestures).

If you want use the `RadDataGrid` and add swipe gestures, you can set `TranslateX` to `ManipulationMode`, add `ManipulationDelta` event and `ManipulationCompleted` event. That you can do the action in the `ManipulationCompleted` event.

For example:

```
<telerikGrid:RadDataGrid Name="MyRadDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" UserEditMode="Inline">
    <telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns >
        <telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Product">
            <telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Product}" ManipulationMode="TranslateX"  ManipulationCompleted="TextBlock_ManipulationCompleted"  ManipulationDelta="TextBlock_ManipulationDelta"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
        </telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns>
</telerikGrid:RadDataGrid>
```